# How do I actually encounter the roaming Legendary Bird (Moltres)?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

In Pokemon x I fly to where Moltres is, but he's always somewhere else! I chase him and chase him but I never catch up to him.

My friends who have caught him say it takes 11 times to be able to catch him but I don't know what Pokeball I need or what will happen if I defeat him by accident! Is there a better more efficient way to catch him somehow?

Comment: Try not flying, but walking/skating to the location. Every time you enter a new location check if it moved. You won't be able to do anything (battle or throw Pokeballs etc) until you've actually enountered it 11 times.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please take a moment to read the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and browse our highest rated question to get a feel for the kind of questions and quality we expect on this site.

Comment: thank you and if he goes into the sea spirits den then should I use a dusk ball?

Answer (score 2):

There's a fairly comprehensive guide [here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-x-y/How_to_Catch_Articuno,_Zapdos,_or_Moltres). The basics are as follows:

> After you defeat the Elite Four, go to any route and walk through any tall grass. A white flash will appear, and you'll come face to face with one of the legendary birds. Unfortunatly, the legendary will flee before you even have a chance to make a move.
>
> After the legendary flees, it will move off to another route. You can check the location of the legendary by finding it in your Pokedex. Keep in mind that the legendary will move to a new route if you pass through too many areas. The legendary also moves every time you Fly to a location.
>
> The legendary will once again flee the second time you encounter it. Follow it to several more locations. After finding it about a dozen time, the legendary will retreat to the Sea Spirit's Den. Head to Azure Bay and enter the cave.

At that point, you just talk to it and capture it like a normal Pokemon.

Finally, there's this tidbit if you're having difficulty tracking it down:

> Fly to South Lumiose City. From this point you have acess to five
>   different, increasing the chances that you fly to a location close to
>   the legendary bird. Fly Couriway Town and use a Max Repel. Hop onto
>   your Bicycle and ride up into Route 18. Ride through the two rows of
>   red flowers, then return to Couriway Town. Continue to repeat this
>   process. The legendary bird should be moving to new routes every
>   couple of times you enter and exit an area. Continue using plenty of
>   Max Repels to avoid any normal wild Pokemon.